# How to create a N-level dynamically changing listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, multi-level

im facing a problem in my project. What im trying to do is,
    i need to parse a json reponse to a listview.

[image]

While clicking the row i will get some id , and now i need to call another webservice using that id and it should show another list .Suppose i clicked the First row ,ie Board "A". Then the next Listview should be the sublist of A . It might look like the following

[image]

A1,A2 etc  may  or maynot have submenus.

I can get the id of from the clicked row . And if the list is empty means no more submenus.
I dont know how to design this system?  Does any one have any idea? Thanks in advance

PS: I will have to make different webservice call to get each submenu that depends on the ID im passing from the listview row click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas to get you started:

1. Instead of using `ListView`, take a look at `GridView`. ListView does not support more than one column (you have to support that manually) and GridView was introduced for this purpose.
2. Let's assume your initial list is shown in its own activity. This means you have an activity which queries the webservice on its `onCreate()` and then displays the results in the ListView/GridView when they are returned asynchronously from the webservice.
3. It will be convenient to hold the submenu in its own activity. This means you should create another activity for the submenu (maybe it can share code with the first one or even be derived from it to reduce code duplication). This activity will receive in its `Intent` an argument (take a look at `Intent.putExtra` and `Intent.getExtra`) which tells it which row was clicked (it should usually contain the String filter you are about to pass to the webservice). Once this activity is created, in its `onCreate` it should query the webservice much like the first activity and show its results in its own ListView/GridView.
4. To connect the two activities you'll need to catch the on click event in the first activity, figure out which row was clicked, and then create an `Intent` to show the 2nd activity, pass the extra and show it.
5. This approach will let the user dismiss the 2nd activity using the back key once they're finished with it. Once it's dismissed, the user will be returned to the 1st activity where they can click on a different row.

Comment: This will work only in two level right?Here i may have n level submenus

Comment: This can work in as many levels as you want. From every activity you can create a new activity of submenus. Android holds all of your activities in a stack, so the user can dismiss them easily and go back to where he wants in the hierarchy and this is managed automatically for you.

Comment: Another comment, if you plan to have N levels, you don't need to implement N different activities. They will normally all share the same code and just be different instances. Use the Intent extras to give your activity runtime arguments on creation.

Comment: Life saving answer :) Thank you so much .The 5 points mentioned in your answer  were exactly what i wanted. :)